# Color Shift when saving rendered image/video

Tags: rendering, image, color

Really frustrating issue going on. When I save a rendered image/video as any file format there's this super obvious color shift that occurs. It pulls down the saturation and boosts the brightness/highlights. The only solution I've found is to correct it via an image editor.

This seems to be the same issue as: [color issue when save my render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183176/color-issue-when-save-my-render). But I am not very smart so idk what to make of the answer— if someone could give me a dummy walkthrough or explanation that would be soo helpful and appreciated.
I'm using Blender 2.92 on a MacBook Pro M1(I know, not ideal)

Rendered image is on the left and the saved image from render is on the right.

[image: color shift]

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set "view transform" to standard?

[image]

Comment: Yes, Standard is what it's set to for this render!

Comment: Ok, then please provide blend file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RMAK4nwP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RMAK4nwP/)

The HDR is missing not sure how to correct it but should still get color shift??

Comment: just because i am curious: how long does it take to render that image on your M1?

Comment: i now saved it as .exr ....this is a bit better - but still not the same

Comment: Blender isn't optimized for the M1 yet so its running through Rosetta 2- that render took almost 6 min at 300 samples with denoising. I'm new to blender so it could probably be optimized better

Comment: thank! and...did you try this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98279/color-difference-in-saved-images-vs-render-view

Comment: @saltyaf I've downloaded the file and the HDRI you used but I can't reproduce this error. Maybe because I'm running on Windows. My render looks exactly like the saved image - which looks like your saved image on the right. The only difference is I don't have that thick dark border on the top... I guess you should have a closer look on that link Chris provided in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks it looks like it may be an Apple issue, ill try rendering on a PC and see what happens!

Comment: So I rendered the image on a PC. The render and saved image were the same- they looked like the saved image above(on the right).

So it seems like on my MacBook the saved image may be correct while the rendered image within blender as well as any color in blender is oversaturated and has its brightness/highlights turned down. Maybe due to my display's color profile or maybe blender's colors work off a different color profile with Apple vs PC??

Comment: I have found 3.0 does not have this issue and cycle render time is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think I figured it out! I opened the saved image in Photoshop, went to *Edit > Assign Profile > Display* (the last option).

This caused the image colors to look exactly as they look in the Blender Render viewer. Which is great if you are just going to be looking at the image on your Mac.

If you want to share it on the web it will not look the same, since the "display" color profile on a Mac has a wider range of colors than a web browser or PC is capable of, which I believe is sRGB.

So if the image is for sharing it makes sense to use the sRGB profile rather than Apple display if you want it to look the same across platforms.