# How to composite images without changing the brightness or contrast or saturation?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image

Let's render an image as an example:
[image]

Now, save the rendered image as a JPG file (called "original.jpg"), and drag it to the Compositing mode, and connect to the Composite node, then save the newly composited image as "new.jpg".

[image]

The following is the comparison between the "orginal.jpg" VS "new.jpg".

[image]

[image]

The brightness or the contrast is changed - "new.jpg" becomes darker and less saturated.

**(1) Why is this happening please?**

**(2) How to avoid or fix this change please?**

---

For those who wonder why I do this is because I want to composite two images together without affecting the brightness or contrast or saturation. For example, let's compose it with an image of red square:
[image]
[image]
Again, the brightness or contrast or saturation of the original image is changed after this composition.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183176/color-issue-when-save-my-render

Comment: Thanks, @Emir ! That link is the comparison between the image in the viewport and the final rendered image. My post is the comparison between the final rendered image and the composited image. Are you sure that these are the same issue please?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. It is very hard to narrow the issue, what you could do is to try some of the answers, another thing could be compression (because of the jpg) or color depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a color space issue. By default, Blender's color space is Filmic. When you add an image in the shader editor or compositor, its default color space is sRGB.

Aside from EXR, color management is saved in the picture. So when you import that same picture, you effectively import a filmic-made picture but interpret it as sRGB.

[image]

Set it to Filmic sRGB and the problem will be solved:

[image]

If you were using EXR images, you would need to use Linear:

[image]

By the way, jpeg is a format for shipping lightweight compressed pictures over the Internet, NOT a format suited for compositing. Targa raw or EXR are made for that.

Comment: Using linear space in EXR does work. Great!